# Express passport check if user connected, in html

Tags: html, node.js, express, passport.js, swig-template

In my web app I have a nav bar with a login button.

But When the user is connected (passport), I want to change "login" by "logout" but I can't check if the user is connected.

This is my code for nav.html

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/home" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about" title="About">About</a></li>
        {{ req.app.get('login') }}
        {% if req.app.get('login') %}
          <li><a href="/logout" title="LogOut">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="/login" title="Login">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

-

```
app.js



 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 req.app.set('login', req.isAuthenticated()) //edit
 next();
});
```

I tried to directly set 'login' at true or false, but in `nav.html` it's still not accessible.

If any one has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `app.get()` syntax to get the value, you need to use `app.set()` syntax to set the value instead of just attaching to the `app` object.

Comment: It would be `req.app.set('login', req.isAuthenticated())` not `req.app.set('login') = req.isAuthenticated()`.

Comment: Changed. But Still don't work. Even if i set manually 'true', this is like if I can't acces the value in the html